# Whats bad with an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

**Why this code doesn't work?** `echo get('option_1')` returns null.

```
$settings= array(
    'option_1' => 'text'
);

function get($name)
{
    if ($name)
        return $settings[$name];
}

echo get('option_1');
```

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php (second example).

Comment: haha, thanks. Forgot about scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to make `$options` be a global variable inside `get()`:

```
function get($name)
{
    global $options;
    if ($name)
        return $options[$name];
}
```

If you don't like global state, make `$options` as an argument to `get()` (but then it's just syntactic sugar...):

```
function get($name, $options)
{
    if ($name)
        return $options[$name];
}
```

Comment: Never do `global`..

Comment: meze, agreed, that's why I've updated the answer.

Comment: global in PHP is not like global in other language, with that in mind I would to enlighten myself why `Never do global`?

Comment: anubhava, it's usually hard to maintain code with a lot of global state. It's easier to encapsulate it in objects. I do not totally agree with the "never do X" sentiment - it can be useful to do X in some situations - but you should think twice about introducing global state in most programs. `global` in PHP basically means that the function will work on *more* data than is provided to the function, which is very similar to global state.

Comment: s/never do X/try to avoid X, and if you do X anyway make sure you know *why* and what the alternatives to X would be/

Answer (score 3):

Because $options is out of the scope of the get function. You either have to:

1. Pass $options along with $name as a function parameter
2. Declare $options as global variable (very bad idea)
3. use $options as an internal class variable and access it with $this->options (only works inside a class)

Comment: global in PHP is not like global in other language, with that in mind I would to enlighten myself why global in PHP is `very bad idea`?

Answer (score 1):

The `$options` is not in the scope of your `get` function.

An object oriented solution:

```
class Options
{
  private static $options = array(
    'option_1' => 'text',
  );

  public static function get($name)
  {
    return isset(self::$options[$name]) ? self::$options[$name] : null;
  }
}

echo Options::get('option_1');
```